# How to set drawing style for QgsRasterLayer in QGIS 2?

Tags: qgis, python, style, qgis-2, map-drawing

I am using PyQGIS.
In QGIS1, I can use:

```
rlayer.setDrawingStyle ( QgsRasterLayer.PalettedColor )
```

but In QGIS2, I got some errors.

I follow [pyqgis developer cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/raster.html), put some demo scripts in qgis python console without success.

```
rlayer.drawingStyle() #got AttributeError
rlayer.setDrawingStyle(QgsRasterLayer.SingleBandPseudoColor) 
#got AttributeError from QgsRasterLayer, change it to QgsRaster
rlayer.setDrawingStyle(QgsRaster.SingleBandPseudoColor) #got TypeError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this code that works for me in qgis 2.2

```
  if bandCnt > 1:
      if Red_band > bandCnt or Green_band > bandCnt or Blue_band > bandCnt:
         raise GeoAlgorithmExecutionException( 'Only ' + bandCnt + 'layers in file')
      if Type == 0:
         rlayer.setDrawingStyle('MultiBandSingleBandGray')
         rlayer.renderer().setGrayBand(Red_band)
      elif Type == 1:
         rlayer.setDrawingStyle('MultiBandSingleBandPseudoColor')
         rlayer.renderer().setGrayBand(Red_band)
      else:
         rlayer.setDrawingStyle('MultiBandColor')
         rlayer.renderer().setRedBand(Red_band)
         rlayer.renderer().setGreenBand(Green_band)
         rlayer.renderer().setBlueBand(Blue_band)
   else:
       if Type == 0:
          if rlayer.rasterType() == 1:
             rlayer.setDrawingStyle('PalettedSingleBandGray')
          else:
             rlayer.setDrawingStyle('SingleBandGray')
       elif Type == 1:
          if rlayer.rasterType() == 1:
             rlayer.setDrawingStyle('PalettedSingleBandPseudoColor')
          else:
             rlayer.setDrawingStyle('SingleBandPseudoColor')
       else:
          if rlayer.rasterType() == 1:
             rlayer.setDrawingStyle('PalettedColor')
          else:
             rlayer.setDrawingStyle('SingleBandGray')
       rlayer.renderer().setGrayBand(Red_band)
```