# PyQGIS cookbook seems out of date

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to follow the http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/ but it seems to be out of date, for example many of the raster methods no longer work as indicated or even exist (eg drawingStyle).
Can anyone suggest a better online resource for learning this stuff?

Comment: The link you're using seems to be for "testing" purposes. Try this [link](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/)

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: Someone posted a possible solution on how to set raster drawing styles for QGIS 2.2 [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83308/how-to-set-drawing-style-for-qgsrasterlayer-in-qgis-2) which may help.

Comment: Thanks for the links. The problems are the same following the non-testing cookbook, and the solution in the second link really only considers that one problem rather than providing a general solution, i.e. an up to date guide.  I'm running the latest QGIS (2.6.0) which may, I suppose, be part of the problem.

Comment: I don't think the docs are updated regularly as I just found the QGIS 2.2 [cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html) and it seems exactly the same as the previous versions. I think the QGIS Team's main focus is the software itself since they have limited resources and funding due to not being commercial. The alternative would be to study the plugin code itself I guess.

Comment: I'm perplexed, reading the comments: I downloaded a variant of the cookbook, and it was not completed, here and there, though it's cover alludes to version 2.2

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).